# My random_walk code results in "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c, linux

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define PI 3.1415926535898

// the usage
void usage(char *program) {
  fprintf(stderr, "\nProgram Usage:\n%s\n", program);
  fprintf(stderr,
          "     [ -n  1000000 ]    number of steps per run, default 10000\n");
  fprintf(stderr,
          "     [ -o output.dat ]  the output file, default: output.dat\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "     [ -h ]             display this information\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
  exit(1);
}

// function to get system arguments from command line
void getMyArgs(int argc, char **argv, int *nstep, char *filename) {
  char ch;
  while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "n:o:h")) != -1) {
    switch (ch) {
    case 'n':
      *nstep = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case 'o':
      *filename = *optarg;//as if there is the error.
      break;
    case 'h':
      usage(argv[0]);
    case '?':
      usage(argv[0]);
    }
  }
}

// function to get the distance from the start point
double dist(double *site) { return sqrt(site[0] * site[0] + site[1] * site[1]); }

// function to output the data
void output(FILE *fp, int istep, double *site) {
  fprintf(fp, "%10d %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f\n", istep, site[0], site[1],
          dist(site));
}

// function to get the step
void getStep(double *step) {
  /* get the degree */
  double deg = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX* 2 * PI;
  step[0] = sin(deg);
  step[1] = cos(deg);
}

// function run the step
void runStep(double *site, double *step,double s) {
  site[0] += s*step[0];
  site[1] += s*step[1];
}

//probability function
bool proba(double p){
    if(rand()/RAND_MAX<p)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}

// the main program
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // for parameters
  int nstep = 1000;    
  char *filename = "output.dat"; 
  getMyArgs(argc, argv, &nstep, filename);

  srand((unsigned)time(0)); 

  // the initial state
  double site[] = {0.0, 0.0};
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
  output(fp, 0, site);

  // walking ....
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <= nstep; ++i) {
    double step[2],s=1;
    if (proba(0.8)==1)
    {
      if(proba(0.5)==1)
      {
        s=0.5; 
      }  
      getStep(step);
      runStep(site, step,s);
    }
    output(fp, i, site);
  }
  fclose(fp);

}
```

It's my `random_walk` code. The function should output `data.dat` when I run `./a.out -n 1000 -o data.dat`. But it always results in **`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`**.

It can output `output.dat` with 1000 statics when I run `./a.out -n 1000`

I guess it should be caused by `filename = *optarg`, but I can't get it correct.

---

I have changed my code as @kaylum said.But GCC show me:

```sh
random_walk.c: In function ‘getMyArgs’:
random_walk.c:30:17: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       *filename = *optarg;
```

And I run `./a.out -n 10000 -o data.dat`, it results in:

```sh
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: "but I can't change it". What do you mean by that? Do you mean you don't know how to change it or you are not allowed to change it? You must change it because it is not correct.

Comment: `getMyArgs(int argc, char **argv, int *nstep, char *filename)` needs to be changed to `getMyArgs(int argc, char **argv, int *nstep, char **filename)` and called as `getMyArgs(argc, argv, &nstep, &filename);`

Comment: It doesn't work.@kaylum

Comment: `*filename = optarg;`